# SQL Join Big data

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

I have this join:

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM `entities_instance` a  
 INNER JOIN `instance_fields_data` artists 
 ON ( a.entity_instance_id = artists.entity_instance_id 
      AND artists.`dynamic_field_name` = 'artists' 
      AND artists.`field_value` like '%8605:%')
 INNER JOIN `instance_fields_data` _enddate 
 ON (a.entity_instance_id = _enddate.entity_instance_id) 
    AND (_enddate.`dynamic_field_name` = 'enddate') 
WHERE a.`entity_id` = 67 
GROUP BY a.entity_instance_id
ORDER BY _enddate.field_value DESC 
LIMIT 100
```

It needs to return about 5 results but instead I get this error:

```
The SELECT would examine more than MAX_JOIN_SIZE rows; 
check your WHERE and use SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1 or 
SET MAX_JOIN_SIZE=# if the SELECT is okay
```

Can someone help me improve this query?
I don't wan't to user the SQL_BIG_SELECTS command.

Thank you

Comment: I'd construct a pseudo-normalized materialized view, then work on that - you know `SELECT a.*, MAX(CASE... WHEN... THEN... END) artist. etc...`

Comment: Applying a group by typically requires some aggregation such as min(), max(), avg(), etc of column(s) in the query.... However, what indexes to you have on the two respective tables... You have WHERE and JOIN which look ok otherwise.

Comment: A composite index on `entity_instance_id, dynamic_field_name` in `instance_fields_data` might be helpful.

Comment: If you gave us the table structures and sample data we could help out more...

Answer (score 0):

Many resources on the net propose running `SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1` as a separate query before your main query.

I'm thinking though, maybe you can try using aliased tables in order to perform a join with smaller data sizes. Not sure but it could help.

**Example:**

```
select a.* from
(select * from `entities_instance` test WHERE test.`entity_id` = 67) as a
INNER JOIN `instance_fields_data` artists 
 ON ( a.entity_instance_id = artists.entity_instance_id 
      AND artists.`dynamic_field_name` = 'artists' 
      AND artists.`field_value` like '%8605:%')
 INNER JOIN `instance_fields_data` _enddate 
 ON (a.entity_instance_id = _enddate.entity_instance_id) 
    AND (_enddate.`dynamic_field_name` = 'enddate') 
GROUP BY a.entity_instance_id
ORDER BY _enddate.field_value DESC 
LIMIT 100;
```

It would help to have a sample of your data and table structures in order to help more.
E.g. we don't even know which table is the one with the most data.

**Example2:**

Here I am taking the where statements for each of the 3 tables, and using them within aliased derived tables.

```
  SELECT a.*
FROM
  (SELECT *
   FROM `entities_instance` test
   WHERE test.`entity_id` = 67) AS a,

  (SELECT *
   FROM `instance_fields_data` test2
   WHERE test2.`dynamic_field_name` = 'artists'
     AND test2.`field_value` LIKE '%8605:%') AS artists,

  (SELECT *
   FROM `instance_fields_data` test3
   WHERE test3.`dynamic_field_name` = 'enddate') AS _enddate
WHERE a.entity_instance_id = artists.entity_instance_id
  AND a.entity_instance_id = _enddate.entity_instance_id
GROUP BY a.entity_instance_id
ORDER BY _enddate.field_value DESC LIMIT 100;
```

**Example3:**

Finally, in this further optimization we make use of `EXISTS` to further filter the results of two subqueries of `instance_fields_data`. I'm sure this can be further simplified/optimized. Also make sure you have indexes on your keys (e.g. entity_instance_id) or this will be slower.

```
SELECT a.*
FROM
  (SELECT *
   FROM `entities_instance` test
   WHERE test.`entity_id` = 67) AS a,

  (SELECT *
   FROM `instance_fields_data` test2
   WHERE test2.`dynamic_field_name` = 'artists'
     AND test2.`field_value` LIKE '%8605:%'
     AND EXISTS
       (SELECT *
        FROM `entities_instance` z
        WHERE z.entity_instance_id = test2.entity_instance_id AND
        z.`entity_id` = 67)) AS artists,

  (SELECT *
   FROM `instance_fields_data` test3
   WHERE test3.`dynamic_field_name` = 'enddate'
     AND EXISTS
       (SELECT *
        FROM `entities_instance` z
        WHERE z.entity_instance_id = test3.entity_instance_id AND
        z.`entity_id` = 67)) AS _enddate
WHERE a.entity_instance_id = artists.entity_instance_id
  AND a.entity_instance_id = _enddate.entity_instance_id
GROUP BY a.entity_instance_id
ORDER BY _enddate.field_value DESC LIMIT 100;
```